# I have a checkbox toggle in my child component, in which I am sending my parameter from parent component. But it's unable to read in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, array

Variable value which I am sending from parent component is getting it's value in child component but it's not getting read in HTML. As, in HTML I'm reading it via for each loop because I am having 3 similar chehckbox toggle. Please check the code for reference and point out my mistake.

Parent Component HTML-

```
<c-task-list-view-configuration-modal is-alliance-lead={is_Alliance_Lead} selected-page-size={selectedPageSize} time-format={timeFormat} wrap-lines={wrapLines} show-table-column-assignee-role=true task-assignment-date=true show-table-column-assignee-email=true ontasksettingsupdate={handleTaskSettings} >
    </c-task-list-view-configuration-modal>
```

Child Component HTML -

```
<template if:true={showColumnsProperties}>
                        <div class="slds-form__item slds-border_left slds-size_1-of-2" role="listitem">
                            <div class="slds-form-element_horizontal slds-p-around_xxx-small" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                <p class="slds-p-bottom_xx-small">{labels.Select_visible_content}</p>
                                <ul role="presentation">
                                    <template for:each={receiveRecord} for:item="lineItem" for:index="index"> 
                                        <li key={lineItem.fieldName} class="slds-p-left_medium slds-p-bottom_x-small slds-border_bottom">
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-p-top_x-small slds-grid">
                                                <div class="slds-p-right_medium slds-p-right_large slds-size_4-of-5">{lineItem.fieldLabel}</div>
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="slds-float_right" name={lineItem.fieldName} value={lineItem.fieldLabel} checked={lineItem.showTableColumn} aria-describedby={lineItem.FieldName} onchange={handleFieldDefinationChange}/>
                                                <span id={lineItem.fieldName} class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                                                    <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                                                    <span class="slds-checkbox_on"></span>
                                                    <span class="slds-checkbox_off"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                       </li>
                                       
                                    </template>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </template>
```

Child Component JS-

```
@track receiveRecord = [
    {   fieldLabel : "Assignee role",
        fieldName : "Assignee role" ,
        showTableColumn : this.showTableColumnAssigneeRole()
    },
    {   fieldLabel :"Assignee email",
        fieldName :"Assignee email",
        showTableColumn : this.showTableColumnAssigneeEmail
    },
    {   fieldLabel :"Task assignment date",
        fieldName :"Task assignment date",
        showTableColumn : this.taskAssignmentDate
    }
];

connectedCallback(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    //this.handleLoadPage();
    this.isLoading = false;
    console.log('this.showTableColumnAssigneeRole '+ this.showTableColumnAssigneeRole); //true
    console.log('this.showTableColumnAssigneeEmail '+this.showTableColumnAssigneeEmail); //true
    console.log('this.taskAssignmentDate '+this.taskAssignmentDate); //true
    console.log('receiveRecord[0].showTableColumn '+this.receiveRecord[0].showTableColumn ); //undefined 
}
```

When I am assigning showTableColumn property to it's respective value and try to have it displayed on UI with for:each loop, it's not working as expected as it is receiving undefined value. I tried to log it in JS. Please check and tell me it's possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was getting override, so to avoid it instead of having true false value in the parent component. I had to assign it to variable first and then assign the variable in parent component HTML.

Parent Component HTML-

```
<c-task-list-view-configuration-modal is-alliance-lead={is_Alliance_Lead} selected-page-size={selectedPageSize} time-format={timeFormat} wrap-lines={wrapLines} show-table-column-assignee-role={isAssigneeRole} task-assignment-date={isTaskAssign} show-table-column-assignee-email={isAssigneeEmail} ontasksettingsupdate={handleTaskSettings} >
    </c-task-list-view-configuration-modal>
```

Parent Component JS-

```
isAssigneeRole= false;
isAssigneeEmail= false;
isTaskAssign= false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace showTableColumn:this.showTableColumnAssigneeRole() with showTableColumn:this.showTableColumnAssigneeRole as *showTableColumnAssigneeRole* is a variable and not a function.

Comment: the "()" must have been added by mistake but, I was doing it without calling it as function only. However, it was not working. I found the solution.